# Using a function to fit a list of pairs

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to use part to take from a list of pairs to manipulate them.

The question is

> Create a function named `fitQ2[d]` which accepts a list of pairs of numbers `{x, y}`. The function should first take the log of the second element of the pair storing the new pair `{x, Log[y]}` in a variable named `tempQ2`.  The function should then use `Fit` to find and return a linear fit.
>
> For rxample: `fitQ2[dataTest2]` should return `1. + 4. x`
>
> Execute `fitQ2[data2]` and `ListPlot[tempQ2]`. You should get a fairly straight line.

I have tried to use

```
fitQ2[x_, y_] := Table[i, Log[y], {i, 0, 10}]
```

I understand this is not correct and I just cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: `Table[{i, Log[y]}, {i, 0, 10}]`.

Comment: It is not clear how `dats2` is created, The first line of your question indicates that forming `dafa2` is the main point od your question, but then you go to show an elaborate question about fitting. Which is your real queation>

Comment: "'data2'" Is a list of given inputs

Comment: What are the values in `dataTest2`?

Comment: '''dataTest2 = {{0, Exp[1]}, {1, Exp[5]}};'''

Comment: Im unsure how to post as a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fitQ2[list_] := ({First@#, Log[Last@#]} & /@ list) // Fit[#, {1, x}, x] &

fitQ2@{{0, Exp[1]}, {1, Exp[5]}}
{* 1. + 4. x *)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now